# Remainder function being arithmetic

Tags: logic

I am reading Kleene's "Introduction to Metamathematics" chapter 9 section 48, where he mentions that "We know that the predicate $rm(c,d)=w$, where $w$ is the remainder when $c$ is divided by $d$, is arithmetical" (1971 ed. pp.239).

I know that $rm(c,d)=w$ is primitive recursive but I have trouble understanding why it is arithmetical. I would like to understand this without using the result that all primitive recursive functions are arithmetical.

Definition: Predicate is arithmetical if it can be expressed explicitly in terms of constant, variable natural numbers, functions $+$, $\cdot$, equality $=$, the operations "implies", "and", "or", "not", and the quantifiers "for all", "there exists", combined according to the usual syntactical rules.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: $\forall c,d\in \mathbb N,\exists ! k,w|c=kd+w \land 0< w\le r; rm(c,d):= w$. Surely that is arithmetical?

Comment: @fleablood Can you please expand a little bit on your notation? I am not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: "For all natural ($0$ is included) $c,d\ne 0$ there exist a unique natural numbers  $k,w$  so that $c = kd + w$ and $0\le w < r$ and we define $rm(c,d):=w$"   Is that not arithmetical?

Comment: @fleablood what is $r$?

Comment: $r$ is a typo for $d$.  I'm just defining the remainder function.  Why doesn't it seem algebraic to you?

Comment: @fleablood Hi, thanks for comments! I would like remainder to have property $rm(c,0)=c$. Using your definition, this is not the case because if $w$ is the value then you require $w<0$.

Comment: My (standard) definition is $0 \le w \le d-1$ (and that $c$ is allowed to be $0$) but it can easily be adjusted to be $1 \le w \le d$.  But that wasn't your question.  You asked why it was arithmetic.  Well, every aspect of it (it's the unique remainder when you divide a number into another) strikes me as arithmetic.  Where is your issue?

Comment: @fleablood After thinking about it, I am satisfied, thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by fleablood in the comments, we can write the relation $rm(c,d)=w$ as $$ w<d\land\exists k (c=kd+w)$$ and, to fully comply with your requirements, $w<d$ can be expressed as $\exists z(\lnot(z=0)\land d = w+z)$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I would like to have the property of remainder that $rm(c,0)=0*k+c$, in other words, $rm(c,0)=c$. Using your definition, this is not the case. Because no matter what value we consider $w<0$ will always be false, so $rm(c,0)=w$ will always be false.

Comment: @DanielsKrimans Yes if we want to make it a total function then I guess we should handle the case of dividing by zero.  Setting the remainder equal to zero in this case sounds fine. So... add a clause to the formula to handle this case.

Comment: @DanielsKrimans I misread: you want to set the remainder when dividing $c$ by zero to be $c$... seems strange to me, but hey, it’s just a default value for a nonsense case, so go for it. And it’s just as easily handled as using zero.

Comment: ..... " I would like to have the property of remainder that..."  you never said anything about defining a new and different arithmetic function.  You asked why an existing and defined function was arithmetic.  If you have a specific question I suggest you actually *ask* that question.  This answers the question that you *did* ask.